# Installing Homebrew + nginx + rtmp in macOS Mojave 10.14

Tags: macos, nginx, homebrew, rtmp

I was able to install Homebrew + nginx + rtmp in macOS High Sierra 10.13. Now I want do the same on macOS Mojave 10.14.

So let's start ... istallation of Homebrew, first we need Xcode in terminal...

```
xcode-select –install
```

than. We need homebrew

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install.sh)"
```

than install nginx + rtmp

**And here's the problem**

I tried:

```
brew install nginx-full --with-rtmp-module
```

but it won't work

the result:

```
Updating Homebrew...
Usage: brew install [options] formula

Install formula. Additional options specific to formula may be appended to the command.

Unless HOMEBREW_NO_INSTALL_CLEANUP is set, brew cleanup will then be run for
the installed formulae or, every 30 days, for all formulae.

    -d, --debug                      If brewing fails, open an interactive
                                     debugging session with access to IRB or a
                                     shell inside the temporary build directory.
        --env                        If std is passed, use the standard build
                                     environment instead of superenv. If super
                                     is passed, use superenv even if the formula
                                     specifies the standard build environment.
        --ignore-dependencies        An unsupported Homebrew development flag to
                                     skip installing any dependencies of any
                                     kind. If the dependencies are not already
                                     present, the formula will have issues. If
                                     you're not developing Homebrew, consider
                                     adjusting your PATH rather than using this
                                     flag.
        --only-dependencies          Install the dependencies with specified
                                     options but do not install the formula
                                     itself.
        --cc                         Attempt to compile using the specified
                                     compiler, which should be the name of the
                                     compiler's executable, e.g. gcc-7 for GCC
                                     7. In order to use LLVM's clang, specify
                                     llvm_clang. To use the Apple-provided
                                     clang, specify clang. This option will
                                     only accept compilers that are provided by
                                     Homebrew or bundled with macOS. Please do
                                     not file issues if you encounter errors
                                     while using this option.
    -s, --build-from-source          Compile formula from source even if a
                                     bottle is provided. Dependencies will still
                                     be installed from bottles if they are
                                     available.
        --force-bottle               Install from a bottle if it exists for the
                                     current or newest version of macOS, even if
                                     it would not normally be used for
                                     installation.
        --include-test               Install testing dependencies required to
                                     run brew test formula.
        --devel                      If formula defines it, install the
                                     development version.
        --HEAD                       If formula defines it, install the HEAD
                                     version, aka. master, trunk, unstable.
        --fetch-HEAD                 Fetch the upstream repository to detect if
                                     the HEAD installation of the formula is
                                     outdated. Otherwise, the repository's HEAD
                                     will only be checked for updates when a new
                                     stable or development version has been
                                     released.
        --keep-tmp                   Retain the temporary files created during
                                     installation.
        --build-bottle               Prepare the formula for eventual bottling
                                     during installation, skipping any
                                     post-install steps.
        --bottle-arch                Optimise bottles for the specified
                                     architecture rather than the oldest
                                     architecture supported by the version of
                                     macOS the bottles are built on.
    -f, --force                      Install without checking for previously
                                     installed keg-only or non-migrated
                                     versions.
    -v, --verbose                    Print the verification and postinstall
                                     steps.
        --display-times              Print install times for each formula at the
                                     end of the run.
    -i, --interactive                Download and patch formula, then open a
                                     shell. This allows the user to run
                                     ./configure --help and otherwise
                                     determine how to turn the software package
                                     into a Homebrew package.
    -g, --git                        Create a Git repository, useful for
                                     creating patches to the software.
    -h, --help                       Show this message.
Error: invalid option: --with-rtmp-module
```

so i tried:

```
brew install nginx --with-rtmp-module
```

but.....result:

```
Updating Homebrew...
Error: No available formula with the name "–with-rtmp-module" 
==> Searching for a previously deleted formula (in the last month)...
Error: No previously deleted formula found.
==> Searching for similarly named formulae...
Error: No similarly named formulae found.
==> Searching taps...
==> Searching taps on GitHub...
Error: No formulae found in taps.
```

so I decided to try install nginx first and than rtmp module

```
brew install nginx
```

and than i tried:

1. `brew install nginx libnginx-mod-rtmp` (copying from Linux)
2. `brew install rtmp-module`
3. `brew install module-rtmp`

But none of the above worked. How do I resolve it?

Comment: I FIND THE SOLUTION  'brew tap denji/nginx' before everything

Answer (score 10):

You should tap a nginx formulae before try install nginx-full

Well you can try `denji/nginx`, since homebrew/nginx tap has been deprecated, That's:

```
brew tap denji/nginx
```

then

```
brew install nginx-full --with-rtmp-module
```

That works for me.